# Retrieve name of PPT object link - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to retrieve the source path link for objects in a PowerPoint Presentation.

At present, I am manually entering the source file path of the excel sheet using FilePath = "C:\source file.xlsx".

Is there any way that the path can be detected and stored as string without hard coding the path or asking user to input it?

Comment: The Environ function is probably what you're looking for.  Here are a couple of links  [Tech on the Net](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/environ.php) and [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/environ-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the source behind a shape to get the source of the linked object : Shape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName

example following code to get the source behind the linked objects:

```
Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide, shp As PowerPoint.Shape, pres As PowerPoint.Presentation

For Each sld In pres.Slides
sld.Select
For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
        ' do something with shp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName

    End If
Next
```

Next

Answer (score 0):

See:
- [Presentation.Name Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.name)
- [Presentation.Path Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.path)

for example:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim ppPath As String, ppName As String
    ppPath = ActivePresentation.Path
    ppName = ActivePresentation.Name
    If ppPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "File not saved"
    Else
        MsgBox ppName & vbLf & "saved as" & vbLf & ppPath
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Here is the code:

```
Dim pptSlide As Slide
Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape

For Each pptSlide in pptPresentation.Slides
    For Each pptShape in pptSlide.Shapes
       If pptShape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or pptShape.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
           Path = pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
           Position = InStr(1, Path, "!", vbTextCompare)
           FileName = Left(Path, Position - 1)
       End If
   Next pptShape
Next pptSlide
```

Path retrieves entire link of object (including chart number and worksheet name), Position detects position of ! in path (after which worksheet name begins). FileName then considers characters to the left of first !, and stores file name as string.